# Retrieve records with date older than 6 months and update a column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get all records where date column is 6 months older than today's date, using Microsoft SQL Server? I want to retrieve those records and also want to update a column active=0 in the same table for those records retrieved

Retrieved the records:

```
SELECT * FROM login WHERE Date <= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())  / gives me ID
```

Update for those ID's retrieved from above query

```
Update Login Set active = 1, UpdateTime = GETDATE(), where ID = 10
```

I want to merge these queries so that it does the update for all the records retrieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM login 
WHERE mydate <= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())

UPDATE login 
SET active = 1, UpdateTime = GETDATE()
WHERE Date <= dateadd(month, -6, getdate());
```

Comment: The above query retrieved the records, is there a way i can update a column in the same table for the ones retrieved ?